# Alternative to auto-increment primary key in MySQL for multi-master replication

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

A webapp I am speccing out is going to need to be horizontally scalable, and will require a pair of MySQL servers from the start (perhaps rising to more than one soon after launch).
As an auto-increment primary key is not suitable, I was wondering what alternatives people use.

Something with the date in makes the most sense, but if you go down to the millisecond level and assume a three-digit server ID it's a very big number:

`sssyymmddhhmmssmicros` or `001110510143622123456` for right now - plus you could perhaps do with another number at the beginning to simplify the leading zeros (datacentre ID, perhaps).

Epoch time shortens it, but only a little.

What else is there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is UUID (Universal Unique Identifier). In MySQL you can generate UUID's whith the function uuid().

```
SELECT uuid();
```

An UUID looks like this 8cb1764a-7b0d-11e0-aaa7-00270e0f8070 ... I know! it's very long but it works.

Comment: Well, that's given me something to think about! It's bigger than my solution, and I'm a bit worried about the performance hit it will cause on large joins (but then, I shouldn't be using large joins anyway). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for are GTIDs. They are unique & work with multi-master replication in MySQL. 
[a link for more details](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-gtids-howto.html)!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you don't want multi-master replication and probably not mysql (have a look at cassandra). But yes, you will need sequences that include a master id. You can emulate sequences by using a seperate table. Look at how PEAR emulates them for example.

Comment: I will take a look at some alternatives, but I suspect I won't use them (part pressure from outside, and part because I'm not *quite* sure I trust them yet). I'm also a bit warey of using a table for sequences because it provides a single point of failure.  Thanks for your answer, though.

Comment: Then you should use a database that provides sequences natively. Using the uuid() is effectively using a sequence, except that they are not sequential. If you just need an unique identifier and it's not important that they are incremental, then uuid is the short answer.